# Parsing mutlipart requests

Tags: java, inputstream, multipart

Excuse me if my english is not very good.

Anybody know how it possible using java to parse a multi-part HttpServletRequest request and not loosing access to the InputStream.

I would like not to make copy of stream in memory due to memory restrictions.

Is wrapping request only means to solve such problems ?

ServletFileUpload.getitemiterator only allows access to the inputstream once for request ?

Thank you again,
Sam.